# Store itemstack and recover it

Tags: java, json, bukkit

I'm trying to store an ItemStack to a JSON file. I would like to know if it's possible to convert the string itemstack to an itemstack. So what I do in my code is that I store the string itemstack in my json file and try to recover it.

```
ItemStack pane = new ItemStack(Material.STAINED_GLASS_PANE, 1, DyeColor.LIGHT_BLUE.getData());
String itemstack = pane.toString();
```

Comment: Save this object in JSON format then you can serialize and deserialize it using Jackson or other libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Jackson library to serialize and deserialize objects. Example:

```java
// serialize pane and save object to file in the JSON format
ObjectMapper objectMapper = new ObjectMapper();
objectMapper.writeValue(new File("target/pane.json"), pane);

// load object from file and deserialize it to ItemStack
ItemStack pane2 = objectMapper.readValue(new URL("file:src/test/resources/pane.json"), ItemStack.class);
```